# Populate list of values for each category

Tags: sql, sql-server

I extract the following table:

`SELECT NAME FROM TABLE`

```
  NAME
  A-1
  A-1
  A-1
  A-2
  A-2
  A-2
  A-2
```

and I have the list of values

`['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', 'value_4', 'value_5',]`

that should be populated for each unique name:

```
  NAME   VALUES
  A-1  value_1
  A-1  value_2
  A-1  value_3
  A-1  value_4
  A-1  value_5
  A-2  value_1
  A-2  value_2
  A-2  value_3
  A-2  value_4
  A-2  value_5
```

How it can be done in SQL? `VALUES` are entered as constants, not from any other table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the list of values actually be contained in another table, then a cross join would work here:

```
SELECT
    n.name,
    v.value
FROM names n
CROSS JOIN vals v
ORDER BY
    n.name,
    v.value;
```

**Data:**

```
WITH names AS (
    SELECT 'A-1' AS name UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A-2'
),
vals AS (
    SELECT 'value_1' AS value UNION ALL
    SELECT 'value_2' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'value_3' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'value_4' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'value_5'
)
```

### Demo

Comment: could you please elaborate on the second one (Data) ?

Comment: @anarz You may view the two _CTEs_ below as proxies for the actual two tables you have which contain the names and values.  I only included this so that someone who would want to reproduce your exact question would be able to do so.  [Check the demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=62960bcbbec64c4f1ce1a3388862fa5a).